# Understanding the minmax algorithm of tic-tac-toe (without recursion)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, minmax

I'm trying to write a minimax algorithm for a tic-tac-toe at Python.
I don't need help with the code, just with the algorithm... :-)
I'm trying to do it **without** recursion, and to understand it better I look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956356/5827215)

So, my algorithm is this:
Lets say that `em` is a list of all the empty squares at the board.
'x' - is the human (or the computer) that palying, and 'o' - is the tree (of the minimax algorithm).
So, the *input* of the algorithm is a tic-tac-toe board, and the *output* as the square of the next move...

I also use dictionary for every empty square, to put there the score for deciding the next move. We will call it `map`...

***The algorithm***

1. Takes all the permutations of `em` at size `len(em)`
2. For every permutation do this:
3. > from the first element at the permutation put 'x' or 'o', e.g. if the permutation is `(2,4,6,7)` so the algorithm will put 'o' at 2 (because it's the tree turn) and then 'x' at 4 and so on...
4. > If 'x' wins at the permutation (it can be at the middle, we don't need to fill it until the end) `map[the_first_element_at_the_permutation]-=10`
5. > If 'o' wins at the permutation: `map[the_first_element_at_the_permutation]+=10`

After all this - we are looking for the element at `map` with the highest score and we return it as the square for the next move....

Unfortunately - It doesn't work... It's works for many cases, but there are few cases that it's doesn't working....
For example:
`x..
.o.
..x`
Now it the turn of the tree, and it will put 'o' here:
`x..
.o.
o.x`
And it's not good because I can put 'x' at the top-right corner and I'll win....

---

What you suggest me to do? Why my algorithm doesn't work? (I work on it for a few days and I don't know hat to do....)

Comment: Have a look at *several* moves (unless you have an immediate win) ahead. There's a good touchstone - the first move at the corner (`a1`, `a3`, `c1`, `c3`) wins unless an opponent puts `o` at the cener (`b2`)

Comment: Yes, it always put the second move at the center (b2) (also if the tree is first)....